# How do sites like Freshbooks and Harvest create individual platforms on different subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

The site I am trying to create will have separate subdomains for each primary admin account.  For the purpose of this question, let's say Google is a customer, so when they register, I need to create the subdomain "google.mysite.com".

From there, different individuals (admin, employees, clients) with different privileges can then log in to the google.mysite.com.

I am using Ruby on Rails as a platform and am a bit lost as to how I would go about doing this.  What is a solid approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is where constraint-based routing can help. By setting a route to accept any subdomain like so

```
get 'photos', constraints: { subdomain: /.+/ }
```

We can then allow the controller to act based on `request.subdomain`.  Railscast has a good [example](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3).

I also believe that the devise gem also offers a similar [solution](http://www.sitepoint.com/basecamp-like-subdomains-with-devise/).

Answer (score 0):

On the operational side, you need to setup your DNS and infrastructure to support this on top of the Ruby code.

#### Wildcard subdomains

A wild card solution will be the easiest to setup as you only need the do the initial setup and any new sub domains will fall into line.

A [Wildcard DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) record will map all of `*.mysite.com` in a single record.

Web servers like Apache httpd and Nginx support [wildcard virtualhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) as well as application hosts like [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) so you can house all your sub domains under the one config.

#### Individual subdomains

Individual sub domains may provide more flexibility in the future for things like load seperation or custom configs on a per domain basis, but will require initial setup each time one of your customers signs up which can involve things outside your Rails App.

For DNS records, I would use a DNS host that provides API's into their administration, like [Amazon Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-Route-53) or [Rackspace Cloud DNS](http://www.rackspace.co.uk/cloud/dns).

For Ruby hosting with API config you might be looking at one of the application hosts like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) as I've not seen a lot of "web hosting" services on the cloud providers with config API's, unless it's for static files.

#### Internal hosting

If your want to host the sites internally it would probably be easier to use one of the API's exposed by hosting control panel products like [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) or [cpanel](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/WebHome) that support web and DNS configuration out of the box rather than rolling your own.